# iOS App Icon Looks Fine Everywhere Except Within Suggestions. Suggestions Icon Has a Black Border. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

The icon I'm using with my app looks fine everywhere on my iPhone X except for when it is listed within Suggestions.

At first I thought this was a cached image from when my version 1 app icon did have curved edges resulting in Xcode automatically adding the black border. I deleted the app from my phone before installing the latest version. Unfortunately, even though I am now on version 2 of my app icon which is completely square the black border still lingers within Suggestions.

What am I missing in order to remove this black border from Suggestions?

**Using my version 2 app icon**

- no black border - good

  [image]
- black border - not good

  [image]

**Xcode icon setup**
[image]

Comment: make sure all app icon size is fine as per apple guideline. I think issue is black background. images is smaller then actual size.

Comment: Even though they are sized accordingly as you can see from the Xcode screenshot above, I'm going to recut the icons per Apple's specs (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/).